# get bytes out of hex-String (PYTHON)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, hex

i have got a problem in splitting a hex- String..
is it possible to seperate the bytes from the String. For example, i received the string :  `80 00 21 80 00 00 92 05`
My Intention is to get the single bytes (80, 00, 21, 80, 00, 00, 92, 05) and translate them into a binary (-String).
Hope u can help me

Steve

Comment: Do you mean `''.join(chr(int(i)) for i in '80 00 21 80 00 00 92 05'.split())` ?

Comment: What do you mean by a binary string? What's the expected output for your given case here?

Comment: i implemented the following code:
`def hex_split(string):
      return " ".join(chr(int(i))for i in string.split())`

`
print(hex_Split("80 00 81"))
`
but I only get: ` P  Q`

Comment: in this case i would like to get a string with the translated hex bytes into binary: `10000000  00000000 10000001`  `(80 00 81)`